# Android MVVM and Intent

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I use Android Arch Components and MVVM architecture in my app.

Model layer and repository classes decide and provide the data to viewmodel and then view layers.

What if the data activity going to use is neither from network or database, but from a previous activity via Intent? What pattern do you follow in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Pass that data to the view model and store it there. 
If it's an id or something partial only, then from view model you can call the model layer.

Comment: Yes. I actually did that on one occasion. Just get the extra from the intent and set the value in the `LiveData' in the ViewModel. In kotlin that's very easy :) Have fun !

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki Can you elaborate? How to pass extra(an object) from a fragment(list) to an activity(detail).

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass If you have some kind of storage for those objects, then the most optimal way is to pass only the id of the object and on the detail-activity get the object based on the id from your storage (ex. repository). If you can't do this, then you will have to make the object parcelable (implement the Parcelable interface) and than you can pass your object to activity in the intent.

Comment: Thanks @kissbudai. I've used a shared ViewModel. It works. I pass the id in a bundle

Comment: I don't recommend the usage of shared ViewModel. A better approach is to have a data layer, for example a Repository class which stores the data (singleton class) and you get what you want from this class directly from the ViewModels, one will get the whole list and the other only an item by id. This way you will achieve a more layered architecture, which will be useful in the future. Maybe this case is simple, but with more logic the shared ViewModel will become unmaintainable.